# Having issues with pulling a date from the spreadsheet

Tags: date, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am working with Google Scripts and here is my problem.

I am attempting to compare today's date with a date entered into column C in the spreadsheet. The code I have seems like it should work but when I use the logger to see the date it gives me "Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 GMT-05:00 1969" instead of 2018-07-29 1:00 PM.

I know I need to use the Utilities.formatDate in order to compare them but I can't seem to understand why it is not pulling the date in column C.

Here is my code below:

```
function sendEmail() {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var startRow = 3;  // First row of data to process
 var numRows = sheet.getLastRow()-1;   // Number of rows to process
 // Fetch the range of cells A2:B3
 var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, sheet.getLastColumn());
 // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
 var data = dataRange.getValues();
 //Logger.log(data); // give you the data you are looking at comparing


for (var i in data) {
 var row = data[i];
 var date = new Date();
 //Logger.log(date); // sets to todays date and time.
 var sheetDate = new Date(row[3]);
 Logger.log(sheetDate); // date in the row you are comparing
```

Comment: Please give both Logger items, and label them    //Logger.log(data);  and    Logger.log(sheetDate);  Also do Logger.log(i) to see its value

Comment: You get this value because row[3] is null or not a valid date. Does the cell contain a date? Does it show a calendar when you double click on it ?  By the way, the assertion about having to use Utilities.formatDate to compare dates is not correct, there are many other ways to go...

Comment: Thank you everyone for the great suggestions. I figured out where I was going wrong.  Dieogo was correct and I had to use the row[2]. I also added a logger for i and I got what I needed. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You're not looking at the value in column C. The method [`getValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) returns a two-dimensional array, and [arrays are 0-indexed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Accessing_array_elements). This means that you should be using a 2 (not a 3), when defining `sheetDate`.

```
var sheetDate = new Date(row[2]);
```

As mentioned in the comments, you don't need to use `Utilities.formatDate()`, but that's a separate issue. I would also try logging the value before converting it to a date (e.g. `Logger.log(row[2])`).